Xamarin Forms Android not accessing internet all of a sudden net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
All of a sudden the internet is not working on my app anymore? Here is my AndroidManifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.jamessuske.registrations">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="Registrations.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:label="Settings" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>

I have no idea why this is all of sudden not working, I even tried to add this:         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
Still did not work. I am testing on a simulator but still was working yesterday...so weird.

its a DNS error.  Have you verified that the server is reachable?

Yes, it works when I run the app in iOS

have you tested with the Android browser?

Does it happen on a physical device? You may also try cleaning your project and build it again.
